# How to display foreign key values in MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am trying my best to get a simple MVC application to display foreign key values, but I just can't get it to work.

Here's my classes:

```
public partial class Kingdoms
{
    public Kingdoms()
    {
        this.Provinces = new HashSet<Provinces>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int KingdomID { get; set; }
    public string Kingdom { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> KingdomNr { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IslandNr { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Created { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Modified { get; set; }
    public bool AtWar { get; set; }
    public string Stance { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Provinces> Provinces { get; set; }
}

public partial class Provinces
{
    public Provinces()
    {
        this.ProvinceData = new HashSet<ProvinceData>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ProvinceID { get; set; }
    public int KingdomID { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string Race { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Land { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Networth { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Created { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Modified { get; set; }

    public virtual Kingdoms Kingdoms { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProvinceData> ProvinceData { get; set; }
}
```

This is in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(int networthfrom = 0, int networthto = 0, int landfrom = 0, int landto = 0, int nwafrom = 0, int nwato = 0)
    {
        var provinces = from p in db.Provinces select p;
        return View(provinces);
    }
```

Now, I have to say that I am using the Add View option in Visual Studio 2012 from this ActionResult. The default View (SearchIndex.cshtml) will show:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.KingdomID)
```

Which will show the ID of the Kingdom. But I want to show the string value Kingdom from Kingdoms class. I have tried the following:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Kingdoms.Kingdom)
```

But that just generates this: Error. An error occurred while processing your request.

I am publishing this application to Azure FYI.

Comment: Is the error a Null reference exception? If so, it could be because Kingdoms are not loaded (lazy loading). I'd suggest creating a view model, and use it in the view

Comment: ViewModels and AutoMapper are your friends. I suggest a good read up on these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite your action:

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(int networthfrom = 0, int networthto = 0, int landfrom = 0, int landto = 0, int nwafrom = 0, int nwato = 0)
    {
        var provinces = db.Provinces.Include(p=>p.Kingdoms);
        return View(provinces);
    }
```

and use 
in view

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Kingdoms.Kingdom)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to show all columns of ***table1HasForeignKey*** alongside some column of another table named ***Table2-has-referenced-PrimaryKey*** . Also table ***table1HasForeignKey*** has a foreign key is referencing to the primary key of table ***Table2-has-referenced-PrimaryKey***. To show a join of two tables, you can follow these steps:

In the action of the controller write:

```
public ActionResult Details(int Id)
    {            
        BussinceLogicLayer.UploadedFileBLL uploadBLL = new BussinceLogicLayer.UploadedFileBLL();
        var details = uploadBLL.Details(Id).ToList();
        return View(details);
    }
```

Where method ***uploadBLL.Details(int id)*** is defined as below:

```
public List<table1HasForeinKey> Details(int Id)
    {
        using (Entities1 context = new Entities1())
        {
            var uploadList = context.table1HasForeinKey.Include("Table2-has-referenced-PrimaryKey").Where(x => x.PrimaryKeyInTable1 == Id).ToList();
            return uploadList;
        }
    }
```